# Get value from method

Tags: java, methods

I have a method witch is called as a parameter like the code below...I need to use the parameter "arry" outside the Oncomplete method, in my code..Is there a way that i can achieve that??

```
 Request request = new Request(session,
            "/fql",                         
            params,                         
            HttpMethod.GET,                 
            new Request.Callback(){         
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    String arry = graphObject.getProperty("data").toString();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a class that extends (implements) Request.Callback and pass it to the method.
This class can store the String arry.

```
class RequestCallback extends Request.Callback {
    private String arry;

    public String getArry() {
      return arry;
    }

    public void inCompleted(Response response) {
      this.arry = graphObject.getProperty("data").toString();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
RequestCallback callback = new RequestCallback();
Request request = new Request(session, "/fql", params, HttpMethod.GET, callback);
...
// after the request is completed
callback.getArry(); // and use it.
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I suggest you do whatever you need to inside the callback. The API seems to have been designed that way for some reason. Probably performance. Apparently `onCompleted()` gets invoked *asynchronously*. As a result when you try to access `arry` right after `new Request()` returns (using a `final` local variable) the value is still null.

But if you still need to do it here is a simple way.

```
final String result = null;
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

Request request = new Request(session,
            "/fql",                         
            params,                         
            HttpMethod.GET,                 
            new Request.Callback(){         
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    String arry = graphObject.getProperty("data").toString();
                    result = arry; // Assign response
                    latch.countDown(); // Mark completion
                }
            }

latch.await(); // Wait for Request to complete

System.out.println(result); // Use result
```

Reiterating again, this will defeat `Reqeust` purpose of being asynchronous and might hit the performance.